# Read barcode from Gallery Image in xamarin c#

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need  to read Barcode from gallery image in android application using `xamarin`.

Comment: With "read barcode from gallery" you mean show the barcode image to the user or you mean read the content of the barcode? Could you provide more information?

Comment: Read barcode from the selected image in the gallery which contains the barcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to read the image file then decode it.

To decode it you can use this library [Zxing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms/). It has a `BarcodeReader` class which contains a `decode` method.

***UPDATE***

Here's how I did it:

Using the library from above, you need to install it in all your projects (Forms, Android and iOS).

Created class to hold you decoding logic (in Forms Project)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ZXing;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ReadBarcode
{
    public class BarcodeDecoding
    {
        IImageHelper _imageHelper;

        public BarcodeDecoding()
        {
            _imageHelper = DependencyService.Get<IImageHelper>();
        }


        public Result Decode(string file, BarcodeFormat? format = null, KeyValuePair<DecodeHintType, object>[] aditionalHints = null)
        {
            var r = GetReader(format, aditionalHints);

            var image = GetImage(file);

            var result = r.decode(image);

            return result;
        }

        MultiFormatReader GetReader(BarcodeFormat? format, KeyValuePair<DecodeHintType, object>[] aditionalHints)
        {
            var reader = new MultiFormatReader();

            var hints = new Dictionary<DecodeHintType, object>();

            if (format.HasValue)
            {
                hints.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, new List<BarcodeFormat>() { format.Value });
            }
            if (aditionalHints != null)
            {
                foreach (var ah in aditionalHints) 
                {
                    hints.Add(ah.Key, ah.Value);
                }
            }

            reader.Hints = hints;

            return reader;
        }

        BinaryBitmap GetImage(string fileName) 
        {
            // Get image file and pass in the bytes array
            // or pass in the image name and load the image from the platform implementation.

            var byteArray = GetBytesArraysSomeWhere(fileName);

            var binaryBitmap = _imageHelper.GetBinaryBitmap(byteArray);

            return binaryBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

We will need to do some processing on each platform, this is why I created an interface `IImageHelper` and we will need an implementation for each platform.

```
public interface IImageHelper
{
    BinaryBitmap GetBinaryBitmap(byte[] image);

    BinaryBitmap GetBinaryBitmap(string imageName);
}
```

This is so you can whether read the image in the Forms project and pass in the byte array representation of the image or you can pass in the image name and read it directly from the platform specific implementation.

Bellow is the Android implementation of the interface above. For this sample I am loading a file I added to the Android project Resources.  Modifying this to load a real image wouldn't be that hard, specially if you use the [Xamarin Media plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media/) .

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ImageHelper))]
namespace ReadBarcode.Droid
{
    public class ImageHelper : IImageHelper
    {
        Context context;

        public ImageHelper()
        {
            context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
        }

        public BinaryBitmap GetBinaryBitmap(string imageName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public BinaryBitmap GetBinaryBitmap(byte[] image)
        {
            //uncomment the line below to use the image that is passed instead of a raw image.
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(image, 0, image.Length);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(context.Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.static_qr_code_without_logo));
            byte[] rgbBytes = GetRgbBytes(bitmap);
            var bin = new HybridBinarizer(new RGBLuminanceSource(rgbBytes, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
            var i = new BinaryBitmap(bin);

            return i;
        }

        private byte[] GetRgbBytes(Bitmap image)
        {
            var rgbBytes = new List<byte>();
            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                {
                    var c = new Color(image.GetPixel(x, y));

                    rgbBytes.AddRange(new[] { c.R, c.G, c.B });
                }
            }
            return rgbBytes.ToArray();
        }
```

Now you have everything needed, it's just matter of setting your page to call the `Decode` method of your BarcodeDecoding class.

My code behind is like this:

```
public partial class ReadBarcodePage : ContentPage
{
    BarcodeDecoding barcode;

    public ReadBarcodePage()
    {
        barcode = new BarcodeDecoding();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var aditionalHints = new KeyValuePair<DecodeHintType, object>(key: DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, value: "TRUE");

        var result = barcode.Decode(file: "image_to_read", format: BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, aditionalHints: new [] {aditionalHints } );

        //Label to show the text decoded
        QrResult.Text = result.Text;
    }
}
```

Note: I am using BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE because this is the type of barcode I created. If you are using something different just select it from the Enum.

Hope this helps.

You can find a full example [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Tests/ZXing.Net.Mobile.NUnit/Test.cs).

Code used from [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/495).

Comment: but while using system.Drawing.Bitmap  in android am getting an error System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception. help me on this

Comment: @apineda, try to add code to explain more, stackoverflow support code more than llinks ..thanks

Comment: @shijinitsme just updated the answer. Added a sample code of how to get it work. Mike thanks for the note.

Comment: @apineda thanks for your detailed answer.It works fine with QRcode.

Comment: @apineda  need to read the barcode in an image instead of QRCode.Tried the below code but fails hints.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, new List<BarcodeFormat>() { BarcodeFormat.All_1D });

Comment: How do you implement this dependency for iOS and UWP?

Answer (score 0):

Zxing is powerful and how I do this too, but I would add I have encountered an occasional BarcodeReader.Decode issue with image resolution that returns a null for near-misses on the physically appearing barcode.

After messing around with some fiddles, I discovered that you can vary the height/width ratio via the following code and often get good results for where before Decode was returning a null:

```
int i = -20;
while (barcode == null && i < 100)
{
    Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(pageImg, new Size(pageImg.Width + i, pageImg.Height + i));
    barcode = barcodeReader.Decode(resized);
    i++;
}
```